# String.Split creating all empty array values

Tags: c#, arrays, string

My code builds a string from a network stream with a StringBuilder.

Then I convert the resulting StringBuilder(myCompleatMessage) into a string with `ToString`.

At this point the string is fine.

I then try to use `.Split()` to separate the string on a '~'

When I try to display the resulting string with a Console or write it to a file I get: "System.String[]" repeated over and over.

my code for this is:

```
byte[] myReadBuffer = new byte[3000];
StringBuilder myCompleteMessage = new StringBuilder();
int numberOfBytesRead = 0;
char[] separatingChars = {'~'};
// Incoming message may be larger than the buffer size.
do
{
    numberOfBytesRead = stream.Read(myReadBuffer, 0, myReadBuffer.Length);

    myCompleteMessage.AppendFormat("{0}", Encoding.ASCII.GetString(myReadBuffer, 0, numberOfBytesRead));

}
while (stream.DataAvailable);
string tosep = myCompleteMessage.ToString();

string[] words = tosep.Split(separatingChars);
Console.Write(tosep);

StreamWriter file = File.AppendText("c:\\Users/edegraaf/Desktop/test.txt");
foreach(string i in words)
{
    file.WriteLine(words);
} 
file.Close();
```

string sample:

> 24.062C  2017-05-31 19:36:20.143767~24.125C  2017-05-31 19:37:21.075028~30.25C  2017-05-31 19:38:21.953599~23.937C  2017-05-31
>   19:47:34.447627~23.937C  2017-05-31 19:47:52.717755~23.812C 
>   2017-05-31 19:49:27.846434~24.0C  2017-05-31 20:01:08.865726~24.125C 
>   2017-06-01 14:38:52.948025~23.375C  2017-06-01 14:39:53.872969~23.187C
>   2017-06-01 14:41:05.187961~28.625C  2017-06-01 15:01:48.22

Can anyone tell me why I'm getting "`System.String[]`"?

Comment: file.WriteLine(words); Should be file.WriteLine(i);

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of writing the values of the array,  you are attempting to write the array itself to the file with this:

```
file.WriteLine(words);
```

While what you needed to do, instead, is this, in order to write the values:

```
foreach(string i in words)
{
    file.WriteLine(i);
}
```

Comment: ok that is really obvious and i feel quite foolish now. thank you for you swift  reply.

Answer (score 0):

Change file.writeline(words) to file.writeline(i). It works